# Sufficient conditions for embedding a set of $n$ points with a given metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: metric-spaces

This is a followup to a question I asked in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296648/embedding-a-set-of-n-points-with-a-given-metric-in-mathbbrn).  I'm posting separately so points can be awarded.

Hopefully someone can help me with a reference for this problem, or the construction.  I have a metric defined on $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  What are sufficient conditions to be able to find a higher dimensional Euclidean space so that you can place $n$ points in such a way that these distances are attained with the standard metric?  If it is possible, is there a formula of some sort to determine the locations (up to rigid motions)?  I understand that is very general and hopefully someone knows of a weak enough set of conditions that it works for the application I have in mind.

To make it more explicit:
If $\{x_i\}$ are the original points with distances $d(x_i, x_j)$ and $\{y_i\}$ are the images in $\mathbb{R}^N$, find $y_i$ such that 
$$|y_i - y_j| = d(x_i, x_j)$$

The linked thread proves it cannot be done in general.

Comment: I think this [MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/33047/33248) answered your question.

Comment: thank you so much, I will close this post.

Comment: Hmm, is there a typical procedure when someone solves a problem with a reference to another thread like you did?

Comment: No, it is not typical. But I'm not familiar with this field and I don't think I can make a reasonable summary of that answer. So I will just leave what I found as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existence of an isometric embedding into a Euclidean space

> there's a necessary and sufficient characterization: the squares of the distances must be of *negative type*: specifically, given the $D_{ij} = d^2_{ij}$ values, then they must satisfy the inequality 
>   $$ \sum_{i,j} b_i b_j D_{ij} \le 0$$ for all real $b_i$ such that $\sum_i b_i = 0$. All of this is discussed rather well in the book by [Deza and Laurent](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-3-540-61611-5).

The quote is from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/33047) by [Suresh Venkat](https://mathoverflow.net/users/972/suresh-venkat).

The aforementioned theorem is due to Schoenberg: see [Metric spaces and positive definite functions](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-044-03/S0002-9947-1938-1501980-0/). The actual computation  of an embedding is addressed, among others, by a 1985 paper  [Solution of the embedding problem and decomposition of symmetric matrices](http://www.pnas.org/content/82/8/2197.full.pdf) (Sippl, Scheraga).